# Good idea to migrate PHP/MySQL website with rich UI to Google websites or Google App Engine?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, web

I have a full fledged PHP/MySQL dynamic website for a medium-large business with a rich jQuery and AJAX UI, and am considering migrating it to Google Websites or Google App Engine. (The website currently uses PHP 5.3+)

I want to know if it's a good idea to migrate to (a) Google App Engine or (b) Google websites.

I've heard Google Websites (b) is mostly for static content and has many limitations.
For GAE (a), the code needs revamping according to GAE's database structure (which is not relational).

So in general I was pretty convinced that it's not a great idea to migrate at all to (a) or (b), but then I've also come across http://www.kirksvillewebdesign.com/google-sites. So I'm a little confused. I haven't found a clear enough comparison between a traditional business hosting solution and Google Websites.

Anyone with any idea or experience on this?

Comment: you can use SQL if you want, it's a new option. Not sure, but you seem to think that GAE is a "website hosting" solution. Sure it is but if that's all you want then there are probably better, cheaper options out there. Yes GAE has "many limitations" but it's a platform as a service so what would you expect?  Amazon offer a lower level of access to the box so perhaps that would be more suitable if you want more control then GAE offers

Comment: I was actually referring to two different things - GAE as one thing, and Google websites as a web hosting solution. The link I mentioned is referring to Google Websites.

Comment: ah, I did not realise that existed! You can use relational DB in GAE.

Comment: are you sure?
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview

Comment: yeah, it's new: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/developers-guide

Answer (score 4):

Google Sites is a web hosting service that is similar to other hosted CMS solutions (hosted wordpress, etc..). This is not aimed at developers, but rather at users or site admins.

Google AppEngine OTOH is a full-fledged managed application hosting service (a [PaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) if you will). It has full set of APIs that enable developers to code many different types of apps: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/apis

For structured data storage you can choose [Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) (high-volume parallel no-downtime NoSQL) or [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide) (MySQL-based simple small).

If you know PHP then you might want to look at [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/), a PHP implementation that runs in Java. It [runs on GAE](http://wiki3.caucho.com/Quercus_Google_App_Engine).

Comment: Thank you. I guess migrating my website to Google Sites won't be a good idea then. 

But for Google Apps - is it a good idea to migrate? Is it a smooth process or a  big headache, what with my PHP applications already tied in with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Choosing GAE will additionally provoke you to make appropriate changes in the code of your application so that it will be compatible with the engine itself.

Moreover you will need to take some time to get acquainted with the demands of the platform.

If you want to get a more adjustable solution I suggest you to rely on [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/)
in the full sense.
You will not need to reconfigure the code of your application and you have all standard software stacks at hand and both PHP and Java are supported.
Here is what serves as a bright comparison: http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/02/27/google-app-engine-vs-jelastic/

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine now supports PHP. More information at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to customize and tailor your needs from any web application, the answer will be NO.